# Existing iOS 6.x project and iOS 7 with XCode 5.x

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ios6.1

I have a existing iOS 6.x project that I developed using XCode 4.x and iOS 6.x and haven't had a chance to get to the App store. I would like to make it work with iOS 7 and also support iOS 6.x devices. I opened the project in XCode 5.0.2 and it complies and runs fine. The only change I think I need to do is UITableView is not looking right as the border lines are off. I'm building the table view thru code.

Also, I'm not using storyboards but using iPhone and iPad specific NIBs.

So, what is the recommended approach?

Create a new brand project in XCode 5 and create the UI and import the code for the methods OR open the iOS 6.x project in XCode 5 and continue with my updates to the code?. I also wanted to support OS 6.x. Do I have to download iOS 6.x SDK and test it along with iOs 7 in XCode 5?

My 4S is jailbroken and running on iOS 6.1.2 and using jailcoder to run on 4S directly.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to start a new project. Just open it in Xcode and it will be upgraded. Make sure you compile against the latest Base SDK, while allowing a minimum deployment target of what you need (iOS6/iOS6.1). You can use the new preview assistant view in interface builder to simulate how it would look in iOS6 and iOS7. You can set deltas in interface builder to set different values between iOS7 and iOS6.

You can download the iOS6.1 simulator from Xcode 5 settings.

Comment: Thanks. I have read articles stating I need to download iOS 6 SDK and copy to a specific XCode 7 folder to get support for iOS 6.x. Is it still a valid?

Comment: @user1739627 No. You need to do all that if you want to compile against the iOS6 SDK. You shouldn't do that. You should compile against the iOS7 SDK and set the minimum deployment target to iOS6. This will allow you to take advantage of the latest and greatest while maintaining backwards compatibility with iOS6.

Comment: Thanks Leo. You have clarified a lot for me. Also, would you be able to reply to my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670585/universal-ios-app-uibutton-and-uitableview-sizes. I have still not fully understood the answers even though I accepted one.

Comment: @user1739627 I will take a look soon.

Comment: @user1739627 What do you need help with?

Comment: Say, I have a button which is sized for iPhone/iPod 3.5 inch. Do I have to use Auto Layout for height, width and the placement of the button when I see it on 4 inch iPhone/iPod?. Now, taking the same button and copying it to a iPad NIB, the first thing is, do I need to first increase the size of the button due to the bigger screen size of the iPad and then use Auto Layout to support both iPad Mini and iPad?. I'm not using storyboards but using NIBs. So, the confusion is what should I do for the button size for different screen sizes (iPhone/iPhone 3.5 & 4 inch) and iPad (Mini and 9.7 inch).

Comment: You cannot go into chat yet, so I'll type here. If you design your views correctly, you do not need to increase the size of your buttons. In fact, most individual elements in iPhone and iPad have the same size. Large iPad screens have larger pixels, so elements appear larger, but they have the same pixel/point size. iPad mini has the same PPI as iPhone, so the elements appear the same size.

Comment: I'm more confused now. I have seen "Cut the Rope" game on iPhone and iPad and also have taken screenshots of the game both on iPod and iPad and seem to believe that the buttons are definitely showing up bigger on the iPad than on the iPod. I have experimented myself with just copying a UIButton from a iPhone specific screen onto a iPad NIB and found that it looks small based on the iPad screen size.

Comment: Are you creating a game? What I meant were system controls. For example, open Mail on iPhone and iPad. Take a screenshot of both and look at them on the same monitor. See that their controls are equally sized. The iPad just has more buttons and more space between them.

Comment: Its not a game. It is more of a brain teaser app. I understand what you're saying. But, as per my testing, the UIButton sized on the iPhone seems to look smaller and tiny when I copied the same exact button from iPhone NIB to iPad NIB and if I make the copied button on the iPad screen slightly bigger using IB, then it looks good relative to the iPad screen size. This is one issue that I'm not getting. Is it ok to keep it at the same size or making it bigger will flag for outright rejection by Apple?

Comment: You don't have to worry about rejections from Apple. You have to worry your UI looks good and is usable. But if you have two different NIB files, why are you worried about sizes? Just set them so they fit correctly in each NIB and you are done.

Comment: Which means I just have to worry about device specific sizes - iPhone/iPod 3.5 and 4 inch and iPad specific (7.9 mini and 9.7). So, for these if I understand correctly using Auto Layout is the best option?

Comment: AutoLayout since Xcode 5 is really good. I would recommend you learn how to use that, yes. Take a look at the WWDC 2013 videos on autolayout.

Comment: Do you have a direct link for that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

BTW, we've been off topic for too long. If this answer has helped you, please accept.